# How to upload images via nginx proxy server with cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, nginx, image-uploading, cloudinary

I'm trying to use [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) in my web service through node js server and all works fine. I'm just interested in uploading images through my nginx proxy without touching of node js backend. Is it possible?

Comment: Cloudinary has SDKs for most of the web platforms. I assume you are using the NodeJS kit, right ? What are you trying to achieve other than this ?

Comment: I want to upload images without touching nodejs

Comment: cloudinary supports upload direct from the browser, see http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery

Comment: I need to check that user authenticated so this approach is not useful for me